# Activereports is removing the last subreport

Tags: c#, activereports

I have a subreport in the detail section of the report that is working for all but the last subreport on each page. When I use keepTogether on the detail section the last subreport just doesn't show up. When I turn keepTogether off it only shows what will fit on the page then throws the rest of it out.

What do I need to look for to fix this?

Comment: probably subreport is initialized in the wrong place, e.g. in BeforePrint event handler or there are some errors in code. i would recommend to send a ticket with sample of project to the official ActiveReports support: http://activereports.grapecity.com/support-ticket/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by GrapeCity Team was right.

I was attaching the subreport in the FetchData event which has worked in other reports. I want to say the reason is because the previous reports I made were designed to fit on one page.

From the AR documentation:
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/Subreport.html

> Coding best practices
>
> Use the ReportStart event of the main report to create an instance of
>   the report for your SubReport control, and then dispose of it in the
>   ReportEnd event. This way, you are creating only one subreport
>   instance when you run the main report.
>
> In the Format event of the containing section, use the Report property
>   of the SubReport control to attach a report object to the SubReport
>   control.